# Qiskit: Get number of iterations for Iterative Amplitude Estimation

Tags: qiskit, programming, amplitude-amplification

Trying to count the number of uses of my circuit $A$ in Grover iterate circuit $Q= -AS_0A^{\dagger}S_x$.

However, Qiskit's amplitude estimation algorithms such as [IAE](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.IterativeAmplitudeEstimation.html) or [FAE](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.FasterAmplitudeEstimation.html)
accept only precision arguments like e.g. confidence of solution, error. I run them like this:

```
from qiskit.algorithms import IterativeAmplitudeEstimation, EstimationProblem, FasterAmplitudeEstimation

problem = EstimationProblem(state_operation=myqc, objective_qubits=[0])
algorithm = IterativeAmplitudeEstimation(**kwargs)
result = algorithm.estimate(problem)
amplitude = result.estimation
```

How can I get the number of total iterations along with the result or at least get the circuit?
Do I need to create my own implementations of the algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the number of iterations, you can do

```
for i,j in enumerate(result_delta._estimate_intervals):
    print(i,np.mean(j))
```

For the circuit result, you can try to do `result.circuit_results`, it might return a Statevector or counts dictionary.
and `algorithm.construct_circuit(problem)` to check the problem circuit.

```
#recommend way to view the problem gate
from qiskit import transpile
transpile(ae_delta.construct_circuit(problem),basis_gates = ['ry', 'cx','ccx','x']).draw()
```

For any more related coding questions, you can just do something like `dir(result)` to see its attribute, then check sources code or docs about these attributes for the explanation.

hope it is something you are looking for

Comment: accept answer will help a lot thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!. Could you elaborate a bit further about the `estimate_intervals` attribute? How is it supposed to help? And why not use `num_oracle_queries`?

Comment: I think you can simply look at the docs and sources code to understand that,  `num_oracle_queries` Return the number of Grover oracle queries. and `estimate_intervals` Return the confidence intervals for the estimate in each iteration.

Comment: Docs helped indeed, but you confused me a bit since I was asking for iterations/queries and you said about `estimate_intervals`. Nevertheless, you helped a lot so I can give you this answer.